# MVC 3: Adding a time to an Event Start Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application I have a section to add an event which has a start date and an end date. I am using the jQuery DatePicker for these two input boxes which works fine.

My question is how can I put a time next to these dates? So that in the database the start date will read (for exampls) "28/06/2011 11:24AM". My intitial thought was to put a text box to the side of the date input box in which the user could enter the time, and then the time could be added to the end of the date field. Almost like StartDate = StartDate + Time

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [following extension](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to the jQuery UI Datepicker useful. And yet [another one](http://milesich.com/timepicker/). And [another](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/). And [one more](http://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/).